# Bubble sort a dictionary

Tags: python, bubble-sort, insertion-sort, selection-sort

I am having problem to implement the bubble, insertion and selection sort. I have no idea how to make the whole thing works. Any kind soul pleaseee

Here below are the object added into the dictionary

```
items = {}
items[1] = Item(1,'Juicy',2,99,'New Zealand','Orange')
items[2] = Item(4,'Sweet',2,99,'Thailand','Mango')
items[3] = Item(6,'Tasty & Sweet',4,99,'Malaysia','Bananas')
items[4] = Item(2,'Juicy',5,99,'Australia','Watermelons')
```

Here below are the sort function but are unable to sort

```
def bubble(theSeq):
n = len(theSeq)
for i in range(1, n):
    for j in range(n - i):
        if theSeq[j] > theSeq[j + 1]:
            tmp = theSeq[j]
            theSeq[j] = theSeq[j + 1]
            theSeq[j + 1] = tmp

def selection(theSeq):
    n = len(theSeq)
    for i in range(n - 1):
        smallNdx = i  # 0
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            if theSeq[j] > theSeq[smallNdx]:
                smallNdx = j
        if smallNdx != i:
            tmp = theSeq[i]
            theSeq[i] = theSeq[smallNdx]
            theSeq[smallNdx] = tmp

def insertion(theSeq):
    n = len(theSeq)
    for i in range(0, n):
        value = theSeq[i]
        pos = i
        while pos > 0 and value < theSeq[pos - 1]:
            theSeq[pos] = theSeq[pos - 1]
            pos -= 1

        theSeq[pos] = value
```

Comment: Without seeing the Item class, how are we supposed to know how they get compared?

Comment: Hey there! A few things.

First of all, it is important to note that your sorting functions address the '0' index (the 'range' function starts with zero), and that index is not present in your indexes.

It's also important to mention that you are comparing instances of this 'Item' class. For custom classes, you have to decide how they are compared (that is, what happens when there is a '<' between them). If you have not done that, you won't get the results you are looking for. Look at how to overload the less than operator: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operator-overloading

Comment: Pleas read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If "Item" is a class, firstly, you should make sure, that you enabled comparison of class instances, using method:  `__le__, __ge__` and so on, secondly, I think you have some problems with first index in your dictionary, which is equal to 1, but in sorting you start counting from 0, in your place I would write this code for insertion sort:

```
def insertion(theSeq):
    n = len(theSeq)
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        pos = i
        while pos > 1 and theSeq[pos] < theSeq[pos - 1]:
            theSeq[pos], theSeq[pos - 1] = theSeq[pos - 1], theSeq[pos]
            pos -= 1
```

But I think, that the main problem is that you can't compare instances of "Item" class, I've run your code on list's with parameters and it went successfully:

```
items = {}

items[1] = [1,'Juicy',2,99,'New Zealand','Orange']
items[2] = [4,'Sweet',2,99,'Thailand','Mango']
items[3] = [6,'Tasty & Sweet',4,99,'Malaysia','Bananas']
items[4] = [2,'Juicy',5,99,'Australia','Watermelons']

insertion(items)
for x in items.items():
    print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will try to use your method and see if it work! Thanks!